# Edit Page of the model doesn't appear as expected in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, metadata

I am creating a MVC project. I try to add a Edit page of a model. Here is my model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace SportsStore.Domain.Entities
{
public class Product
{

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
    public decimal ProductPrice { get; set; }
    public string ProductCategory { get; set; }
}
}
```

As you can see, *ProductId* and *ProductCategory*  property has proper metadata information. As per these metadata information, I shall not see *ProductID* in edit page and see *ProductCategory* in multi line.

Here is my edit page. (edit.cshtml)

```
@model SportsStore.Domain.Entities.Product

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
 }

<h1>Edit @Model.ProductName</h1>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.EditorForModel()
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
@Html.ActionLink("Cancel and return to List", "Index")
}
```

However, I can not see the page in accordance. Here is the view of my page:
[image: output1]

As you can see, ProductID has appeared on the page, and description is not multine. What I am missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for person whom interest with the topic.

The problem is that there are multiple Entity Framework classes in the project mistakenly. Each entity framework has its own Product class. I unite them.